# Use javascript function parameter to get value from object

Tags: javascript, function, object, parameters

I have the following code:

```
var myObj = {apples:"five", pears:"two"};

function myFunction(x) {
    alert(myObj.x);
};
```

When I run `myFunction(apples)` I don't get an alert saying `five`, but I get an alert saying `undefined`.

How do I get the result I want by using the function parameter `x` with the object `myObj`

The result I want is it to say `'five'` instead of `'undefined'`.

Comment: Use brackets like so: `myObj[x]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass the property name as a string.  And within a function use bracket notation (`[]`) for access instead of using a dot (`.`).

```
var myObj = {apples:"five", pears:"two"};

function myFunction(x) {
    alert(myObj[x]);
};

myFunction("apples");
```

Answer (score 2):

For getting a property with a string, you need to use brackets myObj["name"]

Look at this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors

Correct code:

```
var myObj = {apples:"five", pears:"two"};

function myFunction(x) {
    alert(myObj[x]);
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [] notation:

```
var myObj = {apples:"five", pears:"two"};

function myFunction(x) {
    alert(myObj[x]);
};

myFunction('apples')
```